# ADF File Name with Time stamp

Tags: timestamp, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement where I have to store the file in ADF blob in the below format.
Folder1(folder name) --> (Folder2)Date(YYYYMMDD) --> (Folder3)Time(HHMM) --> File(filename)

Eg:  ABC --> 20220221 --> 14:00 --> XYZ.json

How can I pass the folder value dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **parameterize** the sink dataset.

Create parameters for folder name and filenames in the dataset path fields.
[image]

[image]

**Example usage in copy activity:**

`FolderName:`

```
@concat('Folder1Name','/','Folder2Name',formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyyMMdd'),'/','Folder3Name',formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'HH:mm'))
```

[image]

### Result:

[image]